# Firebase login cli is successful, but nothing that requires authentication works afterwards

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I'm simply trying to log in with firebase. Well that actually works, I always get a success message with 'firebase login'. But anything I do, that requires being logged in doesn't work. ex: firebase deploy, firebase login:list etc...

For now, to deploy I do:'firebase login:ci' and then I copy the token and do 'firebase deploy --token "pasted token". But it's really annoying...

Isn't there a way to reset all that? (i tried firebase logout, firebase login --reauth, firebase login:ci --no-localhost)

[image: output]

Please help :)

Comment: I am having this problem.  Did you fin a solution?

Comment: no didn't find any solution to this yet :/

Comment: I eventually deleted my repo directory, created a new one with a different name and cloned the repo once more. This solved my problem but did not really tell me what the issue was.